# Inactive bash terminal runaway error messages

Tags: bash

In a Fedora 30 bash terminal, I use the pdflatex executable to     convert a *.tex
file to a *.pdf file.  Then, I go back to my editor, to make more changes to the
*.tex file.  I've noticed that sometimes, (but not always), **while I am editing**
(i.e. when the bash terminal is **supposed to be inactive**), the bash terminal
will create *runaway error messages*, similar to what is shown below.  Typing
Ctrl-C will stop the messages.  If it is relevant, the bash terminal's font is
"Monospace Regular", and my Fedora desktop is Cinnamon.

What is causing these runaway error messages?

```
"Error (64198): Illegal character ')'" 
"Error: font resource is not a dictionary" 
"Error (64198): Illegal character ')'" 
"Error: font resource is not a dictionary"
...
"Error: Unknown font tag 'F16'" 
"Error (1995): No font in show/space" 
"Error (2011): No font in show/space" 
"Error: Unknown font tag 'F17'" 
"Error (2023): No font in show/space"
"Error: Unknown font tag 'F16'"
"Error (2062): No font in show/space" 
...
```

Comment: Did you start your editor from your terminal and then background it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  Absolutely not.  Editor is emacs, which is started (in Cinnamon) by double-clicking icon.  Bash terminal is Gnome Terminal 3.32.2, which is similarly (separately) started by double-clicking icon.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "bash terminal", and the idea that a terminal emulator should be INACTIVE while you're using another window is absurd. And those runaway messages are from pdflatex, not from the "bash terminal". You're probably saving files in your editor while pdflatex tries to read them.

Comment: Please show the *exact* pdflatex command you were using, including whether it was started in background. If pdflatex was started via a wrapper, show it too.

Comment: @UncleBilly Thanks, very interesting responses.  The exact command is **pdflatex ch02**  Pdflatex interprets this as process ch02.tex.  No wrapper is involved.  My ch02.tex editing, which is done in emacs, is **never** done while the **pdflatex ch02** command is being processed.  By *inactive* I intended that the command I entered had completely finished processing and I had not yet entered another command into the terminal emulator.

Comment: FWIW, these errors are from the poppler library, which is used by pdflatex (or at least it used to be used). But poppler is also used by pdf viewers like evince, so another possibility is that you have started some pdf viewer, which periodically checks if the file has been updated, and complains about (what it thinks) are format errors.

Comment: poppler or the original xpdf program, from which it was derived

Comment: @UncleBilly Again, thanks very much.  I keep qpdfview (ver 0.4.18) always open, and each time pdflatex completes in the terminal, I return to the open qpdfview app and hit its refresh button.  Your explanation is the only tenable one that I've heard re : since the error messages are showing in the terminal emulator which I thought was *inactive*, it seems plausible that some app (e.g. qpdfview) is sending messages to the terminal emulator.